Swiftui view stops updating during scrolling with state change from Combine
My application has transitioned to using Combine with throttle to slow down screen updates. This is working fine except for the side effect that the view doesn't update when scrolling. The code below synthesizes the requirement of my app. Touch the generate sample data button then try scrolling up or down. You'll that the view stops updating until the scrolling stops. Throttle is already using RunLoop.Main. Is it possible to keep the view updating while scrolling and using throttle?
import SwiftUI
import Combine
import Observation

struct Data {
  var a = 0.0
  var b = 0.0
  var c = 0.0
  
}
/// Central store for data
public final class Store: @unchecked Sendable {
  
  private(set) var data = PassthroughSubject<[Data], Never>()
  
  // Singleton instance
  public static let sharedStore = Store()
  
  var timer: Timer? = nil
  
  public func generateSampleData() {
    timer = Timer(timeInterval: 0.025, repeats: true) { [weak self] _ in
      self?.data.send([Data(a: Double.random(in: (-32000)..<(32000)))])
    }
    RunLoop.current.add(timer!, forMode: .common)
  }
  
  public func stopSampleData() {
    timer?.invalidate()
    timer = nil
  }
}

@Observable
public final class ViewModel {
  private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
  
  private(set) var dataSet = [Data()]
  
  init() {
    Store.sharedStore.data
      .throttle(for: .milliseconds(100), scheduler: RunLoop.main, latest: true)
      .sink { [weak self] values in
        self?.dataSet = values
      }
      .store(in: &cancellables)
  }
}

@main
struct IBTTestApp: App {
  @State var generateSamples = false
  @State var viewModel = ViewModel()

  var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
      Group {
        List {
          LabeledContent("Generate sample data") {
            Toggle("", isOn: $generateSamples)
              .onChange(of: generateSamples) {
                generateSamples ? Store.sharedStore.generateSampleData() : Store.sharedStore.stopSampleData()
              }
          }
          Text("\(viewModel.dataSet[0].a)")
        }

      }
    }
  }
}

I'm using Observable framework on iOS 17; thus, the use of @State vs @StateObject. The code is practically a duplicate of tutorials on Combine's throttle operator; for example, this one.

That isn't valid Combine code because you aren't combining anything, i.e. aren't using .combineLatest (or .merge or .zip) and to complete the pipeline it's .assign (not sink or store).  Also it isn't valid SwiftUI either because @State is for values or structs, not objects.

Combine is one of the use cases for ObservableObject vs Observable

@malhal Maybe I'm missing something but the code is practically a duplicate of tutorials on Combine's throttle. Link to such a tutorial added to body of question.
I'm using Observable framework where objects use @State instead of @StateObject.
Problem still persists even if I replace use of Observable framework with ObservableObject, add Published to the property used in the view and change the viewModel from @State to @StateObject.

That tutorial is no good, see the sample here instead https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publisher/assign(to:)

OK. So, I can replace sink with assign(to:) or assign(to:on:). This doesn't make a difference with the original issue: SwiftUI view doesn't update. Regardless of using Observable framework ObservableObject. Why?

Need to use DispatchQueue.main instead of RunLoop.main. DispatchQueue.main is better for UI updates whereas RunLoop.main could get blocked (as is happening when scrolling).

Awesome, exactly what I was looking for!

For future reference: replace .onReceive(text.throttle(for: .seconds(0.1), scheduler: RunLoop.main, latest: true)) { /* ... */ } with .onReceive(text.throttle(for: .seconds(0.1), scheduler: DispatchQueue.main, latest: true)) { /* ... */ }
